# How to use google closure templates for rendering html views in Spring MVC application?

Tags: google-closure

I am building a **RESTFul** web application using **SpringMVC**.For the html views, I intend to use **Google Closure templates**.

Need suggestions on the approach, in case any one in the forum has had this architecture OR even has used google closure templates with a java based web application.

Regards,
AbhishekD

Comment: This is not a **forum**, as in a bbs, this is a Q&A website about specific problems in software development. Please only ask questions about specific problems you have. The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) is a good guide of what should be asked here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just released an initial version of my integration library for Closure Templates and Spring MVC:
https://github.com/tomakehurst/spring-closure-templates

See the wiki for some brief instructions on how to include in your project, and the example app in the source project for a complete example.

In answer to the question below about localisation support, I can quite easily add this if it's going to be of use to anyone. Please message me on GitHub if you have any requests such as this.

Comment: Thanks Tom this was helpful.Also any thoughts on localization..since GCT relies on xliff. Would appreciate if you add the localization features to this code as well.

Answer (score 0):

While i wait for answers/suggestions, thought of proceeding with this approach -

For rendering html output use the Closure Templates as Spring View Resolver components. 
 (Similar to [FreeMarkerViewResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org%20/springframework/web/servlet/view/freemarker/FreeMarkerViewResolver.html))